# Serve deflected to the left hand court in a doubles match, is it a let?

Tags: rules, table-tennis, serve

In a doubles match, is it a let if a serve goes to the left hand court after touching the net?

What if the ball was heading for the right hand court and there was enough spinning to deflect it to the left hand court after hitting the net?

The [ITTF Handbook](http://dr.ittf.com/ittf_handbook/2017/2017_EN_HBK_CHPT_2.pdf) doesn't clarify this edge case:

> 2.9.1 The rally shall be a let:
>
> 2.9.1.1 if in service the ball touches the net assembly, provided the service is otherwise correct or the ball is obstructed by the receiver
>   or his or her partner;

Question 5 in [this link](http://www.allabouttabletennis.com/rules-in-table-tennis.html) says it's **not** a let, but I couldn't find anything more concrete, like an actual occurrence in an official match or a more specific official rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rules you linked to do address this case, albeit not directly. The rule you cited says (emphasis mine):

> 2.9.1 The rally shall be a let:
>  2.9.1.1 if in service the ball touches the net assembly, **provided the service is otherwise correct** or the ball is obstructed by the receiver or his or her partner.

According to the ITTF rules, in a legal service (again, emphasis mine):

> 2.6.3 As the ball is falling the server shall strike it so that it touches first his or her court and then touches directly the receiver's court; **in doubles, the ball shall touch successively the right half court of server and receiver.**

Since the ball, in your scenario, has not touched "successively the right half court of server **and receiver**" it is not otherwise a legal serve, so the server forfeits the point.

You won't find a more specific rule, since the combination of these two rules is clear.

Comment: This exactly.  Think of "let" from the opposite perspective.  An otherwise valid serve that happens to touch the net on its way in is considered a "let".  Any other serve (a serve that hits any other part of the table or misses it), is simply an invalid serve.